# Placing text into an entry box error

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, textbox

I am trying to create a text box that includes text inside of the box but I keep getting an error saying entry has no attribute set. Is there also a way to change the font and size of the entry box.

```
    HeightEntry = Entry(master, textvariable=Height)
    HeightEntry.pack()
    HeightEntry.set("a default value")
    Height = Height.get()

    Height= StringVar()
```

Comment: That's odd, I would expect you to get a NameError there on the first line because you're using `Height` before it's even created. Is this your exact complete code?

Answer (score 1):

Create the `StringVar` before creating the `Entry`. Don't call `Entry.set` to set the value, rather call `StringVar.set`:

```
HeightVar = StringVar() # now created before creating Entry
HeightEntry = Entry(master, textvariable=HeightVar)
HeightVar.set("a default value") # now called on the StringVar, not on Entry
HeightValue = HeightVar.get() # returns "a default value" from previous line
```

You can also do this without `StringVar` by using `delete` and `insert`:

```
HeightEntry.delete(0, 'end') # needed only if Entry contains text
HeightEntry.insert(0, 'a default value')
```

For changing the size and the font see [The Tkinter Entry Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm) by Fredrik Lundh or [The Entry Widget](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/entry.html) by John Shipman.